# Update SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update the commission value column but I want that each row get their values but what happens when I execute that query is that all rows are updated and get the same values.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Table **Discount**

```
Columns: ID, VendorCommisions, CommissionValue
```

Table **Order**

```
Columns: ID, OrderTotal
```

Table **DiscountUsageHistory**

```
Columns: ID, DiscountID, OrderID
```

SQL update statement:

```
    UPDATE Discount 
    SET CommissionValue = (SELECT [Discount].VendorCommissions * [Order].OrderTotal / 100 
                           FROM [Order]
                           INNER JOIN [DiscountUsageHistory] ON [Order].Id = [DiscountUsageHistory].OrderId 
                           INNER JOIN [Discount] ON [DiscountUsageHistory].DiscountId = [Discount].Id)
```

Comment: Please, don't SHOUT in titles...

Comment: WHAT DOES THE SCHEMA LOOK LIKE?

Comment: As posted your query would not work at all because it is missing a closing parenthesis. And logically you have an issue there too because your subquery isn't correlated.

Comment: That query looks malformed, where is your closing parenthesis? `ON [DiscountUsageHistory].Disc` isn't a complete Boolean expression. Also, the table `Discount` in your sub query isn't referencing the one in your `UPDATE` clause, hence why every row gets the same value

Comment: @Larnu Already updated

Comment: Please update the schema information to make it clearer which fields go with which table, and how the tables inter-relate.

Comment: @Brian done itt

Comment: @toutau Where's your `WHERE` clause?? `UPDATE` without `WHERE` will of course update all rows.

Comment: @Eric go check answer below please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below query may help you

```
UPDATE D    
set CommissionValue = (D.VendorCommissions * O.OrderTotal) / 100     
FROM Discount D inner join DiscountUsageHistory DH
on D.id=DH.DiscountId 
inner join Order O on O.id=DH.OrderId
```

Comment: Its not working because is returning more than 1 value so I need to find a way to only update the most recent Row

Comment: I used:  UPDATE Discount set CommissionValue = 
(SELECT[Discount].VendorCommissions * [Order].OrderTotal / 100 FROM [Order]
INNER JOIN[DiscountUsageHistory] ON [Order].Id = [DiscountUsageHistory].OrderId 
INNER JOIN[Discount] ON [DiscountUsageHistory].DiscountId = [Discount].Id 
)
where [Discount].ID in (
SELECT Discount.ID from Discount
INNER JOIN[DiscountUsageHistory] ON [Discount].Id = [DiscountUsageHistory].DiscountId 
Where Discount.ID = DiscountUsageHistory.DiscountId)

Comment: update your question by using 3tables sample data and your expectation from that

Comment: @toutau that means what want to updte

Comment: @toutau then accept answer please and upvote for SO  appreciation